# What is wrong with the following mySQL execution? (Adding data to a table)

Tags: python, mysql, sql

This is the program I have with trying to insert some information into a database;

```
cursor.execute(("INSERT INTO UserDetails "
           "(First_Name,Last_Name,Status,Username,Password) "
           "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",('Adam', 'Smith','Student', 'adamS','password')))
```

When the above program is run, it comes up with the error message;

```
 Server\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 492, in execute
    stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
>>>
```

I was wondering what the reasoning behind the error message is and how it would be possible to overcome it and successfully insert a row into the table.

If it's any help there is a userID column before First_Name.

Comment: Why are you passing a tuple with a string and a tuple to `execute`? Get rid of a pair of `()` there.

Comment: You seem to have an extra pair of `( )` around your statement.